# open cv program crash saying that a error about "libstdc++-6.dll mingw"

Tags: c++, qt5

im very new to opencv. i resently downloaded opencv 2.4.5 configired it correctly with code::blocks. im using mingw4.7 compiler. when i compiled the following code it compiles without errors. but when run the binary it says

`he procedure entry point __gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll`

then i placed the dell file next to the binery from the mingw/bin folder. it didnt solve the problem. then i downloaded the .dll file from the internet and placed it next to the binary. now it didnt give eny error but windows crashes the application and termanite it. i read in the internet that this .dll file have many problems. but i cant solve this alone on my knoladge. if enyone can help me in this issue that would be very great... thanks in eny help...

the code is,

```
  #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
  #include <iostream>

  using namespace cv;
  using namespace std;

  int main( int argc, const char** argv )
  {
    Mat img = imread("MyPic.JPG", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    if (img.empty())          
      return -1;
  }

 namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
 imshow("MyWindow", img); 

 waitKey(0);

 destroyWindow("MyWindow"); 

 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most often reason that this happens is when mixing different flavors of libraries compiled with the mingw gcc compiler TDM-GCC involving the exception mechanisms such as stack unwinding.  There are two methods in common use, DW2 and SJLJ and mixing precompiled libraries between the two methods causes errors as above. Ensure everything is compiled with the same flavor of compiler.

Comment: yes this was a issue with TDM version of the mingw compiler. then i downloaded mingw 4.7.2 from its website and used it the previous error didnt occur. but now it gives a error as `The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000005)` what the reason for this
Click on OK to terminate the application.`

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem, and i resolve as:

In Eclipse-Win7, mingw4.7.2, I just add -lstdc++ to miscellaneous linker flags.